# Trace Table Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, profiler

I have created stored stored procedure to trace mostly used database on my server.

Currently I can get the following:

```
Host Name
Database ID
Database Name
Login Name
Start Time
```

Is there a way I can also get to know the name of the tables being used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Open SQL Server Profiler.
- Use the template: Tuning
- Run trace
- Look at the SQL:BatchCompleted events, at the TextData column. In it you will see the statements that make up the sproc.

Comment: I was thinking of that but I was wondering if there is a way to extract the table name from the TextData Column?

Comment: Is there a way to pull the table Name from TextData column.

Comment: I am trying to create a table that gets populated from the profiler result.

Comment: So far I have the table created and it gets populated  but I want to add a column called table name that extract name of the table from the TextData field

Comment: Or find the table name based on Object but I am not sure what is the object type value for a table in the database

Comment: if you're looking for tables that are bound to specific schemas, you can always use a combination of [string functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx) to extract the table name into a [new column](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic662439-323-1.aspx#bm1087584).